No matching function for call to class constructor?
I am currently working on assignment for one of my classes.
I am trying to construct a class, but when I try to run the program I get this error:
no matching function for call to 'Word::Word()
here is the code that I created:
#include <iostream>
//#include <iomanip>
//#include <string>
//#include <cctype>
//#include <cmath>
//#include <fstream>
//#include <vector>
//#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

string wordToTest;

class Word{
    public: 
        int length;
        string word;
        void TestForPalindrome();
        Word(string w){
            word = w;
            length = word.length();
        }
};

void Word::TestForPalindrome(){
    string testWord;
    for(int i = length; i < 0; i--){
        testWord += word[i];
    }
    if (testWord == word){
        cout << word << " is a palindrome!";
    } else if (testWord != word){
        cout << word << " is not a palindrome";
    }
}
//error happens here
void GetInput(){
    cout << "enter a word: \n";
    cin >> Palindrome.word;
    Palindrome.TestForPalindrome();
}


Word Palindrome;

int main(){
    
    return(0);
}

the error occurs at the comment.
Thanks in advance for any help on this!

The only defined constructor for Word requires a string as a parameter, and Word Palindrome; requires a default constructor (no parameters).

You have multiple problems... Besides the one mentioned by @JonathanPotter you also try to use a variable before it's declared. And using global variables is a bad habit. And to be honest, do you really need a class for this? A couple of normal non-member functions would be much easier.

Just to clarify, the assignment requires me to use a class (for some reason)

@JonathanPotter could you clarify what you mean by requiring a default constructor? I understand what a constructor is for my class but how would it be specific to the definition of Word Palindrome;?

Word Palindrome;  means call a constructor that takes 0 arguments. Another name for such a constructor is the default constructor. Your class has this constructor Word(string w){ which takes 1 argument.

I edited my code to take a string, it still has the same error (edited the post)

@IvanSepulveda: Your updated code compiles. https://godbolt.org/z/foTczjscq

I deleted my answer because of the loop bug in the original code that @jlx  found. Here was my original change that has the bug: https://ideone.com/eDKFjS

Concerning the code that tests for a palindrome: if you were doing this with pencil and paper, would you copy the word backwards and then check letter-by-letter to see if they were the same?

Note: I rolled back your edit because it invalidates the question.  Please do not edit your questions in a way that invalidates existing answers.

Because you only define one constructor that requires a string, so you must initialise Palindrome with a string. So you can use a temporary string to receive the input. By the way, global variable is not recommanded.
Here the update GetInput():
void GetInput(){
    string tmp; // Use a temporary string to receive.
    cout << "enter a word: \n";
    cin >> tmp;
    Word Palindrome(tmp); // Initialise with the temporary string.
    std::cout << Palindrome.word << std::endl;
    Palindrome.TestForPalindrome();
}

I also find another issue with your code: in the function TestForPalindrome():
for(int i = length; i < 0; i--){
        testWord += word[i];
    }

You want to create a reversed string of word, however, since length is greater or equal than 0, and the condition of loop is i < 0, so code in this loop will never be executed.
Here is an update of the loop:
for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        testWord += word[i];
    }


Thank you, I tried doing this once and the code was still erroring. the error visual in vscode was not disappearing for whatever reason..... silly mistake or software issue?

What is the issue of vscode? I'm also using vscode.

Was it a real compiler error or red underlines in the IDE? Sometimes the underlines will be wrong. The purpose of Intellisense is to give a very quick answer and to be correct most of the time. However it does get things wrong.
